# Save base64 encoded image as JPG instead of PNG

Tags: php, base64, file-put-contents

I am saving a base64 encoded image using this simple PHP script...

```
define('UPLOAD_DIR', 'upload/');
$img = $_POST['imgBase64'];
$img = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $img);
$img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
$data = base64_decode($img);
$file = UPLOAD_DIR . uniqid() . '.png';

file_put_contents($file, $data);
```

This works great but the image is always a PNG.  I have tried changing the extension to JPG in the hopes that it would work but it doesn't.

Do I need to save it as a PNG first then convert it to a JPG?

Comment: Let me quote Shakespeare on that: "A rose by any other name would smell as sweet"

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you must convert the image into JPG at first.